# Problem with using "Database Administration Tool Extensions for Windows" in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql, azure-data-studio

I want to `Generate Script` in `Azure Data Studio` by using `Database Administration Tool Extensions for Windows` as it is mentioned in these [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852790/script-database-with-azure-data-studio),[b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392849/how-to-create-script-table-data-in-azure-data-studio) questions.
However, after installing the `Database Administration Tool Extensions for Windows`, when I `right-click` on the database, the following items is appeared without `generate Script`.

[image]

Would you please guide me? thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Thanks for asking. It seems that "Generate Scripts.." is only available on Database nodes at Azure Data Studio, I solved my issues by using "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)" that has "generate scripts" as well.

Comment: I know SSMS has that option by default, but I am trying to export a schema SQL file from Azure Data Studio.

Comment: I understood, but please consider that according to the "Azure Data Studio", the "Generate Scripts..." for the Generate Scripts Wizard is only available on Database nodes.

Comment: I am checking the "Generate Scripts" on the Database node only, check the screenshot. https://paste.pics/I9O61

Comment: Thanks for providing the image; I solved my issue by connecting to Azure through SSMS and then "generate script" by SSMS. I did this as I could not generate scripts by Azure Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After reading this:

> Generate Scripts Wizard is only available on Database nodes", and had a look to the connections "tree", there is only one database there, that's why it shows no "database nodes", but combines it to the "connection node"

Solution: When you create the connection, don't choose a specific database and leave the selection as "default". Then it will show you every common database in the connection; e.g., master...

Now you have your "database node" and can use the extensions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34758790)